# Pointcut that intercepts execution of methods starting with prefix-1 of classes starting with prefix-2?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm wondering if it's possible to write @Pointcut execution expression that will match only specific methods from the specific set of classes within the given package. Say, the package is:

`x.y.z.service`

with some interfaces and their implementation classes inside:

```
x.y.z.service.Foo1
x.y.z.service.Foo1Impl
x.y.z.service.Foo2
x.y.z.service.Foo2Impl

x.y.z.service.Bar1
x.y.z.service.Bar1Impl
x.y.z.service.Bar2
x.y.z.service.Bar2Impl
```

I need to catch with aspect only those methods from `Foo*`, that start with `httpRequest`. Some methods from `Bar*` also start with `httpRequest`, but the pointcut should ignore those. Tried the following (with some variations) but doesn't seem to trigger anything:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* x.y.z.service.Foo*.httpRequest*(..))")
public void httpRequest() {}

@Around("httpRequest()")
public Object doSomethingHere(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {...}
```

Is it at all possible to make an expression of the sort and what would be the correct way?

Comment: Your `@Pointcut` and `@Around` look correct. Did you enable AspectJ with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` ?

Comment: Seems that it worked when I added an extra `.` after `.service.` so the expression looks like: `execution(* x.y.z.service..Foo*.httpRequest*(..))`. Still don't quite understand why is the sub-package dot necessary here...